# Split continuous array into subarrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to convert an array formatted as the following:

```
object(Categories_store_tree)#519 (1) { 
    ["list_of_sections":"Categories_store_tree":private]=> array(5) {                  
        ["id"]=> int(1) 
        ["name"]=> string(11) "Main Store" 
        ["parent_id"]=> NULL 
        ["children"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> array(5) { 
                ["id"]=> int(2) 
                ["name"]=> string(4) "Food" 
                ["parent_id"]=> int(1) 
                ["children"]=> array(0) { } 
            } 
            [1]=> array(5) { 
                ["id"]=> int(3) 
                ["name"]=> string(14) "Electronics" 
                ["parent_id"]=> int(1) 
                ["children"]=> array(2) { 
                    [0]=> array(5) { 
                        ["id"]=> int(4) 
                        ["name"]=> string(8) "Headphones" 
                        ["parent_id"]=> int(3) 
                        ["children"]=> array(0) { } 
                    } 
                    [1]=> array(5) { 
                        ["id"]=> int(5) 
                        ["name"]=> string(5) "Smartphones" 
                        ["parent_id"]=> int(3) 
                        ["children"]=> array(0) { } 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

To this structure of array:

```
object(Categories_store_tree)#964 (1) { 
    ["list_of_sections":"Categories_store_tree":private]=> array(5) { 
        [0]=> array(4) { 
            ["id"]=> int(1) 
            ["name"]=> string(11) "Main Store" 
            ["parent_id"]=> NULL 
        } 
        [1]=> array(4) { 
            ["id"]=> int(2) 
            ["name"]=> string(4) "Food" 
            ["parent_id"]=> int(1) 
        } 
        [2]=> array(4) { 
            ["id"]=> int(3) 
            ["name"]=> string(14) "Electronics" 
            ["parent_id"]=> int(1) 
        } 
        [3]=> array(4) { 
            ["id"]=> int(4) 
            ["name"]=> string(8) "Headphones" 
            ["parent_id"]=> int(3) 
        } 
        [4]=> array(4) { 
            ["id"]=> int(5) 
            ["name"]=> string(5) "Smartphones" 
            ["parent_id"]=> int(3) 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Currently I am doing in manual but the idea is to make it automatic. I have tried with this code, but it returns an empty array, I have also tried with a function but I have been stuck for a couple of days and don't know what to do.

```
$clean_array = array();
            $cont = 0;
            foreach ( $new_tree as $key => $value ) {
                if ( is_array( $value ) ) {
                    $cont++;
                    foreach ( $value as $key1 => $value1 ) {
                        if ( is_array( $value1 ) ) {
                            $cont++;
                            foreach ( $value1 as $key2 => $value2 ) {
                                $clean_array[$cont][$key2] = $value2;
                            }
                        } else {
                            $clean_array[$cont][$key1] = $value1;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $clean_array[$cont][$key] = $value;
                }
            }
```

Comment: That's not an array, it's an object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this.

Convert the object To an array:

```
function objectToArray($d) {
    if (is_object($d))
       $d = get_object_vars($d);
       return is_array($d) ? array_map(__METHOD__, $d) : $d;
}
```

Then:

```
$arr = objectToArray($object);
print_r($arr);
```

[Source](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-tip-convert-stdclass-object-to-multidimensional-array-and-convert-multidimensional-array-to-stdclass-object/)